# how to completely remove mongoDB with all instance from ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

How to completely uninstall mongoDB with all its instances, and re-install it.

I've tried this,

```
sudo service mongod stop

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*

sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

But its giving the below error :

> sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb its giving error :rm: cannot remove
>   '/var/log/mongodb': No such file or directory
>
> sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb its giving error :rm: cannot remove
>   '/var/lib/mongodb': No such file or directory

Now still, it's not removed completely.

> reema@reema-s ~> mongo MongoDB shell version v4.0.11 connecting to:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
>   2019-07-25T15:45:34.860+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect
>   to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException:
>   Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused
>   : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17 @(connect):2:6 exception:
>   connect failed reema@reema-s ~>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the below steps accordingly:

First stop the mongod process

- `sudo service mongod stop`

Remove any MongoDB packages

- `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`

Remove MongoDB databases and log files

- `sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb`
- `sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb`

Remove MongoDB Service

- `sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service`

For **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** use this path `sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

This should work for you.

Comment: can you please specify which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: after you uninstalled MongoDB, there was still a file /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service which is used to start/stop/restart MongoDB service via systemctl. Now you can try removing mongodb.service for that use $ sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service and then check if it is uninstalled. Good luck

Comment: after doing this please confirm if this worked, if not then paste the error code here will try to resolve it with different way.

Comment: Thank u .. Mr. Shaikh
MongoDB uninstalled and then re-installed successfully.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, the path of mongod service is `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the above answer you may also like to run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Sometimes if multiple versions were installed this is also required.